# iTerm2 Get Current Session Profile?

Tags: applescript, iterm, iterm2

So I know there is a way to set the session profile via echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=Foo\a" but is there a way to get the current session's profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any way to get the name of the profile apart from something like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm"
    keystroke "i" using command down
    set p to value of text field 1 of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1
    click button 1 of window 1
end tell
p
```

You might be able to identify profiles by some properties:

```
tell application "iTerm" to tell current session of terminal 1
    background color is {0, 0, 0} and transparency is 0.0
end tell
```

Properties documented in the dictionary:

background color, background image path, bold color, contents, cursor color, cursor_text color, foreground color, id, name, number, selected text color, selection color, transparency, tty

Comment: Yah unfortunately there is no binding in the term :(

Answer (score 12):

You can get the session by checking the `$ITERM_PROFILE` variable (For those looking now). It can help to look at the printout from `printenv` to see things like this.

Comment: awesome looks like they added this in version 3!

Comment: But this `ITERM_PROFILE` environment variable won't change after you edit the current session's profile.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest Applescript I have come up with to do this:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    get profile name of current session of current window
end tell
```

And here's a simple bash script which uses this to set a profile, run a command, then set the profile back again. It uses the first argument as the profile, and the rest as the command (e.g. *script < profile > < command >*).

```
#/bin/bash

#get the current window settings
CUR_SETTINGS=`osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm-2"
get profile name of current session of current window
end tell'`

#Restore the current settings if the user ctrl-c's out of the command
trap ctrl_c INT
function ctrl_c() {
        echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$CUR_SETTINGS\a"
        exit
}

#set profile
echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$1\a"
shift

#run command
$@

#Restore settings
echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$CUR_SETTINGS\a"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.